# Make video responsive (100% of the browser)

Tags: html, css, video, responsive

Hey I can't get this video to go responsive to 100% width of the browser.

Been trying everything but it just doesn't want to work.

HTML is

```
<section class="section-video">
  <video id="321-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls poster="/img/video-poster.jpg" data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="http://media.tptg.co.uk/external_templates/video/321.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="http://media.tptg.co.uk/external_templates/video/321.webm" type='video/webm'>
  </video>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.section-video {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  video {
    object-fit: contain;
  }
}
```

Using this also in my video.css https://pastebin.com/PLZHbRXQ

Test site link is at http://chummy-taro.cloudvent.net/

I just want to have the poster image and the video go max width and auto height.

Comment: You're not targeting your video tag in your css

Comment: I've added     .section-video video {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      video {
        object-fit: contain;
      }
    } still no luck

Comment: What is the exact problem? Is your video loading? It works for me but I had to add a video source first.

Comment: That isn't valid CSS so is it SASS or what? You need to tag it. In addition, those of us who don't use preprocessors can't help you. You need to show the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `video` to your `.section-video` class in the css like so: `.section-video video {`

Example below

```css
.section-video video {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  video {
    object-fit: contain;
  }
```

```html
<section class="section-video">
  <video id="321-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls poster="/img/video-poster.jpg" data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="http://media.tptg.co.uk/external_templates/video/321.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="http://media.tptg.co.uk/external_templates/video/321.webm" type='video/webm'>
  </video>
</section>
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Hey just tried that, no change. Test site link updated.

Answer (score 0):

a) remove fixed height, width from class.

```
.video-js {
/* width: 300px; */
/* height: 150px; */
}
```

b) remove absolute position from the video:

```
.video-js .vjs-tech {
/* position: absolute; */
/* top: 0; */
/* left: 0; */
/* width: 100%; */
/* height: 100%; */
}
```

Note: If you cannot remove fixed inline width/height which I assume is added using JavaScript you may override it with CSS !important (would avoid this solution if possible)

[image]